# Im trying to find out what type of snail this is

Tags: species-identification, invertebrates, molluscs

The snail is pretty large and located in texas.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing it's an invasive apple snail, popular in fish tanks.

http://texasinvasives.org/animal_database/detail.php?symbol=15

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pi2wcFPPJsI

Some people keep apple snails as pets, they are very interesting to keep for a while.

Your photo doesn't give enough info, location, sea or pond, clear image of shell, underside, soft body, to say for certain. apple snails have a wide variety of colors.

Comment: Thank you! My friend and I believe you are correct.... it was about 6 inches long and spotted in a park that has a large pond.